# app can run on emulator but can't run on phone

Tags: android, database, encoding, android-emulator

i'm building an android quiz app which take questions from the data.txt, the ecoding in data.txt is "utf-8" . but my android quiz app can run on emulator but it's doesn't work on my phone. when i change the encoding "utf-8" to encoding "ANSI" this app can run on my phone. how can i run it which encoding "utf-8"? please help me!

Comment: in which device have you tested it?

Comment: @give us information about which device you are using ?

Comment: i tested it on sony xpreria arc s.

Comment: it's has no errors in Logcat. i tested in HTC Desire HD and it worked verry well.

Answer (score 0):

device is not supportive, check in any other device, if problem occurs, then place you error or logcat report